# Warum werden Verben nach Personen konjugiert?

Tags: grammar, difference, verb

Verben werden im Deutschen – wie auch in anderen Sprachen – nach der Person konjugiert, z.B.

> - *ich sprech**e***
> - *du sprich**st***
> - *er sprich**t***

Im Englischen wird eine derartige Unterscheidung <del>nicht</del> kaum vorgenommen.

> - *I speak / I **am** speaking*
> - *you speak / you **are** speaking*
> - *he speak**s** / he **is** speaking*

Warum ist es im Deutschen so?

Gibt es Beispiele für Sätze, in denen die Konjugation des Verbes der Person nach zum Verständnis notwendig ist, z.B. um Unklarheiten zu vermeiden?

Comment: Auch das Englische hat, jedenfalls im _simple present_ und in einigen Zeiten mit Hilfsverb (wo das Hilfsverb im _simple present_ steht), noch Reste einer Konjugation nach Person und Numerus: _I speak_, _she speaks_; _I have spoken_, _she has spoken_; _I am speaking_, _you are speaking_, _she is speaking_.

Comment: Vielleicht gibt es keinen Satz, wo nicht aus dem Kontext klar ist, was gemeint ist, aber mit Konjunktion ist es einfacher?

Comment: Gehört eher zu Linguistics, da das Merkmal nicht auf die dt. Sprache beschränkt ist, und im Vergleich mit anderen Sprachen mehr Sinn ergibt.

Comment: Man beachte, dass man die Frage auch dahingehend stellen könnte, dass die Subjekte angezeigt werden, die Redundanz ließe sich schließlich auch auflösen, wenn man die Subjektinformationen in das Verb packt. In jedem Fall ist die Frage nach dem *warum* hier etwas unangebracht, da niemand die Sprache konstruiert hat und ihr somit keine Intention zu Grunde liegt. Die zusätzliche Redundanz bzgl. des Subjekts ist aber sicher hilfreich bei der Verständigung, und ein typisches Merkmal natürlicher Sprachen.

Comment: *Redundanz* ist ein wichtiges Merkmal der meisten real existierenden Sprachen - Ganz einfach, weil auf dem Weg von Mund zu Ohr viel Information verloren gehen kann. Ich glaube, dass gerade dann, wenn eine Sprache in einem *nicht hart abgegrenzten* Gebiet wie in den deutschsprachigen Ländern entsteht, ist Redundanz umso wichtiger - sie erlaubt es einem Plattdeutschredner, sich mit einem Bayern zu unterhalten, weil er immer wieder bekannte Bruchstücke findet. Das mag auf einer Insel wie GB ein bißchen anders sein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ja, es gibt Beispiele, bei denen es einen Unterschied macht. Hier ein Beispiel:

> Auf jeden Fall, da waren diese Kinder und diese Frau. Sie **ging** dann weg und verschwand aus meinen Augen.
>
> Auf jeden Fall, da waren diese Kinder und diese Frau. Sie **gingen** dann weg und verschwanden aus meinen Augen.

Im ersten Fall geht die Frau weg, während im zweiten Fall die Kinder weg gehen.

Außerdem gab es das im englischen früher auch...

Bspw. `I am` -> `Thou art` -> `He/she/it is` -> `we are` -> `ye are` -> `they are`

Im englischen ist es dann später bloß weggefallen.

Comment: @Armin Fehlt da ein Wort im zweiten Satz des Beispiels? 'Sie ging(en) dann auf jeden weg und...'

Comment: @Robert gedankenvermischung, des jeden muss weg, danke xD

Comment: @Marzipanherz ich mach des jeden weg, da ich des jeden fall schon drin hab, aber danke xD

Comment: Jetzt ist es klarer. Trotzdem noch eine Anmerkung: im zweiten Beispiel könnten auch Frau *und* Kinder gemeint sein. Das ist ohne Kontext nicht ganz eindeutig..

Comment: @Marzipanherz nein, da ich es gibt 4 personen/gruppen in diesem beispiel, einmal ich, der erzähler, einmal der, dem ich erzähle, die frau und die kinder. da ich über die frau/die kinder erzähle ist das eindeutig entweder die frau oder die kinder. es könnte höchstens noch sein, dass ich denjenigen sieze, dem ich des erzähle. aber es kann nicht die frau oder die kinder sein

Comment: ich meinte, die Frau und die. Kinder könnten auch gemeinsam weg gegangen sein, oder?

Answer (score 7):

Natürliche Sprachen werden nicht konstruiert. Es ist nicht so, dass sich jemand hinsetzt und sich ungefähr folgendes überlegt:

> Hm. Wenn wir die Verben nicht irgendwie konjugieren, kann das zu Unklarheiten führen. Also bauen wir irgend etwas ein, um das zu beheben. Mal sehen, vielleicht hilt es, wenn wir die Verben nach den Personen konjugieren. Also machen wir das ab jetzt so.

So entsteht keine einzige natürliche Sprache. Die Regeln, die in einer Sprache gelten, sind vielmehr das Ergebnis eines Prozesses, der sehr eng mit der Evolution verwandt ist, die die vielen verschiedenen Arten von Lebewesen hervorgebracht hat. Da hat auch niemand gesagt:

> Hm. Wenn wir den Affen drei oder vier Arme geben, tun sie sich vielleicht nur weh. Also geben wir ihnen lieber nur zwei, das sollte ausreichend sein. Und Haare anstelle von Federn machen sich bei Affen auch besser.

Auch bei Sprachen entstehen die Arten, wie gesprochen wird, durch das Sprechen, und dadurch, wie gut sich die kleinen Variationen, die es ständig gibt, durchsetzen können.

Wenn eine Variation eine Verwechslungsgefahr vermindern kann, begünstigt das natürlich den Fortbestand dieser Variation, aber viele Regeln, die in Sprachen gelten, könnte man genauso gut durch ganz andere ersetzen, ohne, dass dadurch ein Nachteil entsteht.

Das beweisen ja auch die vielen Dialekte, die in fast allen Sprachen entstehen. Das sind Variationen dieser Sprache mit anderen Regeln.

Die einzig richtige Antwort auf die Frage *warum* es diese oder jene Regel in einer bestimmten Sprache gibt, lautet daher:

> Weil diese Regel zufällig so entstanden ist, und sich nicht als überaus nachteilig erwiesen hat.

Hinter einer bestimmten Regel eine Absicht zu vermuten, ist - zumindest bei natürlichen Sprachen - Unsinn.

---

### Ergänzung

(als Antwort auf Kommentare)

Ich habe [eine meiner Bachelorarbeiten](http://www.grin.com/de/e-book/148855/genetische-algorithmen-in-der-praxis) über genetische Algorithmen geschrieben. Genetische Algorithmen sind - etwas vereinfacht gesagt - Computerprogramme, die sich nach den Regeln der natürlichen Evolution fortpflanzen, wobei jedes Programm Eigenschaften seiner beiden Eltern erbt, und einer geringfügigen, aber völlig zufälligen, und vor allem völlig ziellosen, Mutation, unterliegt. Diese Programme mussten in meiner wissenschaftlichen Arbeit eine bestimmte Aufgabe erfüllen, nämlich ein bestimmtes Brettspiel (eine 3D-Variante von Tic-Tac-Toe oder Vier-Gewinnt) besser als ihre Verwandten spielen. Jedes Programm paart sich bevorzugt (aber nicht ausschließlich) mit guten Spielern. Jede Generation (außer der ersten) besteht ausschließlich aus Programmen, die auf diese Weise aus der Elterngeneration entstanden sind. Kein Programm lebt länger als eine Generation.

Das Ergebnis meines Versuches war sehr eindeutig: Die Programme aus späteren Generationen haben alle das Spiel wesentlich besser beherrscht als die zufallserzeugte Adam&Eva-Generation. Nach nur wenigen Dutzend Generationen spielte auch das schlechteste Programm einer Generation besser als das beste Programm der Startgeneration.

Das Wichtigste dabei: Niemand hat den Programmen beigebracht, was gute und was schlechte Züge sind, und es gab auch sonst keine Gründe, warum die Programme von Generation zu Generation immer besser spielen sollten. Und trotzdem sind am Ende aus einer völlig ahnungslosen Start-Generation wahre Experten entstanden.

Der einzige Grund, warum die Programme so gut geworden sind, sind einerseits zufällige Variationen und andererseits die schlechten Chancen der schlechten Variationen, sich fortzupflanzen.

Und ganz genau so funktioniert auch die Evolution der Lebewesen, und auch die Evolution der Sprachen.

Wenn eine Gruppe von Menschen an Verben bei bestimmten Gelegenheiten Suffixe anhängen, während das die Mehrheit nicht tut, ist das eine zufällige Variation. Wenn anderen Menschen diese Variation besser gefällt als die bisherige Gepflogenheit (etwa weil die Variation leichter auszusprechen ist, weil sie lustiger klingt, weil sie den Sprecher klug wirken lässt, oder weil sie Verwechslungen vermeiden kann), dann hat sie eine erhöhte Chance sich unter den Sprechern zu verbreiten als eine Variation, die nicht so gefällig ist.

Auf diese Weise entstehen ganz leicht unterschiedliche Weisen zu sprechen, die sich entweder in der gesamten Sprechergruppe ausbreiten (was die Sprache als ganzes verändert), oder zur Entstehung von Dialekten führt, wobei diese Dialekte sich weiter auseinander entwickeln können, was zur Entstehung neuer Sprachen und sogar neuer Sprachfamilien führen kann.

Es ist aber falsch zu glauben, dass die Evolution nur Verbesserungen hervorbringt. Die Evolution weis nichts von guten und schlechten Lösungen. Daher ist auch die Frage nach einem tieferen Grund unsinnig, was einige Beispiele aus dem Reich der Lebewesen zeigen:

- Warum hat die Evolution bei den Wirbeltieren Augen entwickelt, wo die lichtempfindliche Seite auf der Rückseite liegt, also hinter der Schicht mit den Blutgefäßen und Nerven? Bei den Tintenfischen hat die Evolution das besser gelöst, die haben Augen ohne einen blinden Fleck.
- Warum baumeln die Hoden bei Männern außen am Körper herum, wo sie leicht verletzt werden können? Elefanten haben auch 37°C Körpertemperatur und funktionierende Hoden, die tief im Inneren des Bauches gut geschützt sind.

Diese Liste von nicht-optimalen Resultaten der Evolution könnte ich noch um viele weitere Beispiele verlängern. Was ich sagen will ist aber, dass die Evolution ihre Entscheidungen völlig grundlos trifft, und dass in manchen Fällen sogar das Ergebnis um einiges schlechter sein kann als eine gesteuerte, also von einem Grund ausgehende Entwicklung.

Comment: +1, das sieht man auch daran, dass die grundlegendsten Verben (sein, gehen, ...) in fast allen Sprachen unregelmäßig sind. Bei jedem neuen Verb, das dazukam, hat man wahrscheinlich unbewusst ausgehandelt, wie man es ähnlich zu vorigen Verben konjugieren könnte. Und mit der Zeit wird das dann konsolidiert, vgl. buk -> backte.

Comment: Dass es keine zentralistische Instanz mit Absichten gibt ist das eine, Gründe kann es dennoch geben. Ob die immer erforscht und erforschbar sind ist eine andere Frage.

Comment: So viel Text und nichts zu der konkreten Frage.

Comment: @CarstenS: Ich finde, ich habe die konkrete Frage »*Warum werden Verben nach Personen konjugiert?*« ziemlich wohlbegründet mit »*Weil diese Regel zufällig so entstanden ist, und sich nicht als überaus nachteilig erwiesen hat.*« beantwortet. Du kannst der Meinung sein, diese Antwort sei unzutreffend, aber du kannst mir nicht vorwerfen nichts zur konkreten Frage geschrieben zu haben.

Comment: Das ist zwar ein guter Versuch, auf die eigentliche Frage nach dem Warum einzugehen. Allerdings befriedigt mich die Antwort nicht, dass «diese Regel zufällig so entstanden ist, und sich nicht als überaus nachteilig erwiesen hat». Die Konjugation nach Person ist viel zu verbreitet, als dass man sie bloss mit Zufall erklären kann. Vielmehr gibt es eine naheliegende Erklärung, die über den Zufall hinaus weist: Die Unterscheidung zwischen verschiedenen handelnden Personen ist ein grundlegendes Muster im Leben aller Menschen. Daher ist es naheliegend, dass Verben immer die Person mitbezeichnen.

Comment: @mach: Wenn das so ist, warum ist das in vielen anderen Sprachen nicht der Fall? Die am meisten verbreiteten Sprachen der Welt konjugieren ihre Verben gar nicht nach der Person  (z.B. Chinesisch), oder nur in einer sehr rudimentäten Form (Englisch).

Comment: Laut [WALS online – Chapter Syncretism in Verbal Person/Number Marking](http://wals.info/chapter/29) haben nur 58 von 197 Sprachen keine Konjugierung nach Person. Das ist ein starker Hinweis darauf, dass es mehr als blosser Zufall ist. Englisch hat zwar nur eine reduzierte Konjugierung nach Person, aber dafür gehört es zu einer Minderheit von Sprachen (laut [WALS online – Chapter Expression of Pronominal Subjects](http://wals.info/chapter/101) 82 von 711), in denen das Subjekt vorhanden sein muss, entweder als Nominalphrase oder als Pronomen.

Answer (score 2):

Ein klassisches Muster für Personenendungen findet sich zB im Lateinischen, wo für jede Person eine eindeutige Endung vorhanden ist:

- amo amas amat - amamus amatis amant (ich liebe, du liebst, er liebt etc)

Diese Personenendungen sind meiner Meinung nach nichts anders als Personalpronomen, die hinten angehängt und verkürzt wurden: ego - ich, am-o ich liebe, eigentlich "lieben/liebend+ich".

Mit der neuen Erfindung, die Personalpronomen vor das Verb zu stellen und nicht dahinter, wo sie verkürzt werden und zu Unregelmäßigkeiten führen - mit dieser neuen Erfindung waren die Verbendungen für Person überflüssig, aber viele Sprachen, wie Deutsch oder Französisch haben Reste behalten. Englisch hatte im Altenglischen ebenfalls Personenendungen, hat sie aber alle abgebaut bis auf s/es für die 3. Person Singular im Präsens.

Comment: Deutsch ist doch aber keine Latein-stämmige Sprache? Darüber hatte ich auch nachgedacht.

Comment: Deutsch und Latein sind verwandete Sprachen.   http://www.janzbikowski.de/spr/familien.png

Comment: Ich denke, das wäre überzeugender, wenn es im PIE wie im Lateinischen war. Was weiß man dazu?

Comment: Latein, Griechisch, Sanskrit haben alle etwa ein ähnliches System der Personenendungen. Wenn man ein PIE konstruiert, muß man es in gleicher Weise mit Personenendungen konstruieren. Aber ich beschäftige mich nicht groß mit PIE. In Latein sieht man vieles besser.

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe einmal gelesen, dass Lateinisch und Französisch die bevorzugten Sprachen für Juristen sind, weil bei Gesetzen oder auch nur Vertragstexten in jedem Satz ziemlich klar wird, von wem bei welchem Aspekt gerade die Rede ist. (Das ist natürlich auch auf andere, hier nicht genannte, Merkmale der Grammatik zurückzuführen, wie die Anzahl grammatischer Fälle.)

Dass es viele Kontexte geben mag, in denen man auch ohne diese Stützen auskommen kann, ist m. E. kein befriedigender Grund, darauf zu verzichten. Da Sätze häufiger gelesen als geschrieben warden, ist Zusatzaufwand beim Schreiben immer gut investiert, wenn es darum geht, Information umfassend zu übertragen.